# Automatically calling server side class without <a href="#" class...>

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an anchor which calls a server side class when clicked, but I want to modify it so that the class is called as soon as the page loads, without having to click an anchor.

```
<a href="#" class="_repLikeMore" data-id="1234" data-type="pid" data-app="forums">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the click event like this:

```
$('._repLikeMore').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with jquery, how do I do that? I've added `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">$('._repLikeMore').trigger('click');</script>` to the head, but it didn't work.

Comment: Like this? `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('._repLikeMore').trigger('click');
  }
</script>`